# Jackson: conflicting @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSerialize(as=Klass.class)

Tags: java, spring-boot, polymorphism, json-deserialization, jackson2

**The problem**

I need to polymorphically JSON-(de-)serialize an `@Autowired` Spring bean (I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.4) using only original properties.

Since the bean is "enhanced", it is a subclass of my "original" bean, with class name ending with something like `$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$12345`.

**Tried so far**

To avoid Jackson trying to serialize the "enhanced" part, I've declared my bean as a supertype of itself with

```
@JsonSerialize(as=MyClass.class)
```

It worked as intended.

But, when I try to do polymorphic serialization with

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
```

placed on the interface that the said class implements, the key of the wrapper object is the name of the enhanced class! The rest of JSON string is OK, that is, only properties of the "original" class are included. Needless to say, I can't de-serialize it now, since the mentioned subclass is not around any more.

Using `JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME` defeats the whole idea of polymorphic deserialisation, IMHO. I can figure out the target class by querying `ApplicationContext`, if nothing else works.

**EDIT:**

Here is a Foo Bar example:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
public class Foo {

  private String foo = "Foo";

  @JsonSerialize(as = Bar.class)
  public static class Bar extends Foo {
    private String bar = "Bar";
  }

  public static class UnwantedMutant extends Bar {
    private String aThing = "Not welcome";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    UnwantedMutant mutant = new UnwantedMutant();
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(mutant));
  }
}
```

This prints

```
{"mypackage.Foo$UnwantedMutant":{"foo":"Foo","bar":"Bar"}}
```

while

```
{"mypackage.Foo$Bar":{"foo":"Foo","bar":"Bar"}}
```

is expected/desired.

**So, the question:**

is there any solution to this problem with "pure" Jackson means, or I just have to live with it?

Comment: @MithatKonuk : the links you've mentioned both describe JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME scenario, which is not acceptable, see the question. Imagine serializing instances of 30 different implementations of an interface - register each of them in the interface declaration?

Comment: @ badbishop i did not realize that !

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with:

`@JsonRootName(value = "NameOfYourClass")` ?

Sorry if I didn't understand your question.

Comment: I've tried now, but it doesn't solve the issue. It wraps the object one more time. I can't remove @JsonTypeInfo, because then Jackson wouldn't know how to deserialize. Sure, I can get it straight fiddling with JsonObject, but I'm looking for a solution not requiring such efforts.